# Can I plot *after* setting slider values?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I have some fundamental misunderstanding of the use of Mma's GUI elements, and I would appreciate some guidance.  I would like to be able to set up a calculation based on slider values and *then* press a button to do the calculation. The calculation may be lengthy, so I do not want it dynamically updated. I think (?) I can illustrate the issue with a plotting example that does not work. Can I set the parameter in a slider but only update the following plot when I press a button?

```
ClearAll[h, k]
h[k_] := Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0., 2. Pi}, PlotLabel -> Sin[k x]];
DynamicModule[{k = 1},
 Column[{h[Dynamic@k], 
   Row[{Slider[Dynamic@k, {Range[10]}], Dynamic@k, Button["plot", h[k]]}, Spacer[2]]}]]
```

I hope this failed attempt will highlight my misunderstanding of the core issues, as I would like to receive some conceptual guidance. I usually find the Mma docs amazingly helpful, but not in this case.

Comment: Who is the audience for this GUI? Is it enough that the button effects a Shift+Enter so it evaluates a cell for instance? Some more info on the use-case would be nice.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I don't think the context matters much, but consider a notebook of simulation models for students to experiment with interactively. Functions will be defined globally but the model parameters should be set (via a GUI) in an isolated (per model) way. (Thus the `DynamicModule` wrapping the controls.) The important thing is to be able to change the parameters *before* initiating the computation. See [typical NetLogo models](https://www.netlogoweb.org/) for illustrative examples.

Comment: While I think its a good idea to learn more about Dynamic, here is solution using built-in options to Manipulate: `Manipulate[h[k], {k, 1, 10}, ContinuousAction -> None]`.  The key piece is ContinuousAction.

Comment: @chuy That's great, but (iiuc) it won't meet my needs, since there will be multiple sliders to set before the expression should be evaluated. Thanks!

Comment: It should behave the same way with multiple controls.  It won't update until the 'U' button is pressed.

Comment: @chuy Aha! This was not clear from the documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the button update a variable: "kk", that will govern the plot:

```
ClearAll[h, k, kk]
h[k_] := Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0., 2. Pi}, PlotLabel -> Sin[k x]];
DynamicModule[{k = 1}, 
 Column[{Dynamic@
    h[kk], {Row[{Slider[Dynamic@k, {Range[10]}], Dynamic@k, 
      Button["plot", kk = k]}, Spacer[2]]}}]]
```

Before clicking "Plot"

[image]

After clicking "Plot":

[image]

Comment: Cool. If I move kk into the module variables this does what I want. I had focused on applying dynamic to variables, not to compound expressions. Can you elaborate on the meaning of "displayed form" in the docs for `Dynamic`?

Comment: "displayed form" means what you see on screen, not the actual code that you can get with "FullForm"

Comment: Yeah, I got that. But I don't know how to interpret it in the context of the docs.  I think the relevant text to improve my understanding is rather this: "`Dynamic[expr]` evaluates `expr` whenever it needs its value and it determines that any type of value of symbols on which it depends might have changed."

Comment: In that documentation, however, the phrase "whenever it needs its value" is mysterious to me.

Comment: My interpretation: when it needs the value and in addition, it notes that the value has changed.